# How do you change syntax coloring in Eclipse for JSP scriptlets?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

When I open a jsp file in the JSP Editor in Eclipse only keywords and strings are colored in the scriptlets, though outside the scriptlets everything looks okay. How do I change the syntax coloring in the scriptlets, preferably using the settings I've already set up for Java?

I'm using the Java EE bundle of Eclipse Indigo, and a java 1.6 jdk.

Comment: Try Aptana; plain Eclipse JSP editing is sub-optimal at best. Better yet, don't use scriptlets--that's 10-year old programming methodology and anti-best-practice.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm trying to fix a preexistent program so I have to use scriptlets right now, but I'll keep your advice in mind. What is the current best-practice that should be used in place of scriptlets?

Comment: JSTL and/or custom tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: highlight the piece of code that you want the changes to be made, right-click on it, go to preferences> {whatever you are trying to change the settings of,for e.g., jsp,etc.} > Editor > Syntax coloring and make the changes that you want. Hope this will help you.